# how to write custom query in cake php helper class

Tags: php, cakephp, helper

i have some function in common Helper , i want to retrieve data from mysql data base then how to connect data base from helper class method ,

i tried to this :

```
 $qryres=mysql_query("select * from hotels where status='1' order by order_id asc") or die(mysql_error());
echo $num_row=mysql_num_rows($qryres);
```

this text show  :  Aucune base n'a été sélectionnée

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. To maintain some quality, could you please format your question by adding 4 spaces in front of code (and skip a line). see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Why you need to write custom query in helper. you can do this on controller and model also. helper is not the place where you write query

Comment: Please make some research and try before asking here. There is lot of tutorial on the web explaining step by step what you want. Take a look to prepared statement and PDO, it's the good way to use sql databases. `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: There should be no reason for querying the database from a helper. This is not the Cake way. You should be preparing your data in your Controllers. If you have common functionality that needs to be shared by your controllers then either put it in AppController or in a Component.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja "*preparing your data in your Controllers*" that's plain wrong. All data processing should happen in the model (or service) layer. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/UrtaH.png

Comment: @burzum oops bad choice of words. I meant setting data for the view. I completely subscribe to the fat models skinny controllers thinking and that's surely why using a helper to query the database is wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Amazing how much can be done wrong in such a few lines of code:

- `mysql_*` functions are **[deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)** for years, there is a big red warning on on that page.
- You're not using the CakePHP ORM
- Access to the model layer in the view layer is a MVC violation (means its a bad thing to do, bad practice resulting in unmaintainable messy code)

Recommendation:

- Get used to work with documentation and start reading documentation *before* writing any code
- [Read about MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
- [Read the CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html) *from the very beginning*, don't skip 1/2 of the book. Especially pay attention to the MVC part and do the tutorials to get at least some basic knowledge about how to use the framework.